# How to play a song with intent

Tags: android

I tried to play the song picken up by intent but I am getting these errors

> E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0xb400007abddc1780)
> error (-38, 0)
> E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean songExists = false;
    Uri songData;
    private MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addSong(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }

    public void playSong(View v) {
        if (songExists) {
            prepareMediaPlayer();
            if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaplayer.pause();
            } else {
                 mediaplayer.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void prepareMediaPlayer(){
        try {
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(songData.getPath());
            System.out.println(songData.getPath());
            mediaplayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
           Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               songData = data.getData();
               songExists = true;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: `songData.getPath()` -- do not call `getPath()` on a `Uri`. Use [the version of `create()` that takes a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaPlayer#create).

Comment: Okay thanks it worked